# IIS Suddenly getting "page cannot be found" 404 error After using remote debugging - Episerver

Tags: visual-studio, iis, remote-debugging, episerver

Earlier today my site was running fine. I had an issue where I needed to attach to the IIS process to debug some of my code. The debugging session crashed. I then went to browse my site and from then on have been receiving the "page cannot be found" 404 error. This is an Episerver site.

I have tried:
Restarting Site,
Recycling App pool,
Restarting IIS,
Restarting machine

I have also checked the IIS logs but it doesnt show any errors.

My other IIS sites are fine its just the one where I was attaching to process where its broken.
Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I realized I could access the CMS section of the site.

If you ever get this issue when remote debugging with Episerver it may be because you were publishing a change in the CMS while remote debugging.

I went in the CMS published a quick change and it sprung back to life.